# doesn't getting desire output in Perl

Tags: perl

```
my $utfSmiley = pack 'U*', 0x263A;
#print "length of \$utfSmiley = ", length($utfSmiley),
 #     ", length of 0x263A = ", length(0x263A), "\n";
 open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $utfSmiley; 
print  binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"),$utfSmiley,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
1☺ #how to remove this 1
```

in my output have `1`.how to remove this and what is the cause for this or is there any thing wrong in my code.please let me know
your answers will be appreciate.

Comment: Note that instead of `pack`, one would write in this case: `$smiley = "\N{U+263A}"` or `$smiley = chr 0x263A`.

Comment: Why was this question closed? I wish all questions were this clear! Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $utfSmiley = pack 'U*', 0x263A;
# open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $utfSmiley; 

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
print  $utfSmiley,"\n";
```

You're printing return value of `binmode` alongside with `$utfSmiley`.

[perldoc binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html)

> Returns true on success, otherwise it returns undef and sets $!

Comment: shall you explain what is the functionality of `A`?

Comment: @user3114045 `0x263A` is hex representation of utf char